# Error while baking

Tags: baking

I am baking tezos, I checked logs and saw errors:

```
Apr 10 06:25:07 xxxx /var/log/tezos/tezos_endor.log[14727]: Apr 10 06:25:07 - client.scheduling: Error while baking:
Apr 10 06:25:07 xxxx /var/log/tezos/tezos_endor.log[14727]: Apr 10 06:25:07 - client.scheduling: Error:
Apr 10 06:25:07 xxx /var/log/tezos/tezos_endor.log[14727]: Apr 10 06:25:07 - client.scheduling:   No Ledger found for focused-abyssinian-xxxx-xxx/ed25519
```

Does anyone know this error? I imported ledger information already.

Comment: Is your ledger connected ?

Comment: my ledger is not connected. we need to keep ledger connection while baking?

Answer (score 4):

**Your Ledger device must stay plugged in and running the baking app to be able to bake and endorse blocks.** Once the device is set up, you do not need to manually sign when you have rights - it will automatically sign for you!

It sounds like you have already imported the address you'd like to bake with. If not, plug your Ledger into your machine and open the Tezos Baking app. Then run:

`tezos-client list connected ledgers`

You should see that it found your device and provides a few commands for importing addresses. Here's an example of one of those which imports an address from the device and gives it the alias `ledger_alias`, which you'll use to refer to your address when running other commands:

`tezos-client import secret key ledger_alias "ledger://adjective-animal-adjective-animal/ed25519/0'/0'"`

Once imported, we can 1) setup the Ledger to bake for `ledger_alias` and 2) register `ledger_alias` as a delegate (baker) on the blockchain.

1 - `tezos-client setup ledger to bake for ledger_alias`

If your Ledger isn't authorized, the device will read 'Baking Key: No Key Authorized' from the baking app. Once it is authorized, it will show your PKH (most likely a `tz1` address).

2 - `tezos-client register key ledger_alias as delegate`

Then start your baker and endorser so they use that account:

- Baker: `tezos-baker-003-PsddFKi3 run with local node ~/.tezos-node ledger_alias`
- Endorser: `tezos-endorser-003-PsddFKi3 run ledger_alias`

That's it! For more information, here's the full docs for Tezos Baking - https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos#using-the-tezos-baking-application

Comment: Thank you, but I already did it. i have been baking for 25 days, but no rewards received. Can you help check the correctness of my baking. https://tzscan.io/tz1e2meErj7eEfXwqr7bDK6N1YatmLaugfMp

Comment: why i missed a lot of endorsements while commands like 
1. tezos-baker-003-PsddFKi3 run with local node ~/.tezos-node ledger_<...>_ed_0_0
2. tezos-endorser-003-PsddFKi3 run ledger_<...>_ed_0_0
3. tezos-accuser-003-PsddFKi3 run
running.

Comment: You need to have your ledger connected while baking. Please double check that it is plugged in and the Baking app is open

Answer (score 1):

Your baking instance cannot find your ledger device. Make sure it is plugged in and that you can see it with `tezos-client list connected ledgers`. The device needs to remain connected while baking.